# TSQL - Efficient method to find where a number falls in a list of values?

Tags: t-sql

This seems simple; I have to be missing something straight forward.

**TestTable**

Value1 (int)

Value2 (int)

Value3 (int)

Value4 (int)

Insert into TestTable 20, 30, 40 ,50

Value1 = 20
Value2 = 30
Value3 = 40
Value4 = 50

I have the number 37. I want to return 30 and 40 (37 falls between these two numbers).

What is the most efficient way using TSQL?

Comment: `Value1` to `Value4` are different columns? Does this table have a PK?

Comment: Apologizes; To clarify Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4 are column data. Yes, there is a primary key. I was trying to keep the structure simple as a post; looks like I didn't provide enough information. "Select PKID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4 From TestTable" would be a simple query

Comment: Why are you keeping data in columns that obviously should be kept in rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @TestTable table (Value1 int, Value2 int, Value3 int, Value4 int)
insert into @TestTable values (20, 30, 40, 50)

declare @Value int = 37

select
  case
    when @Value between Value1 and Value2 then Value1
    when @Value between Value2 and Value3 then Value2
    when @Value between Value3 and Value4 then Value3
    when @Value > Value4 then Value4
  end as Val1,   
  case
    when @Value < Value1 then Value1 
    when @Value between Value1 and Value2 then Value2
    when @Value between Value2 and Value3 then Value3
    when @Value between Value3 and Value4 then Value4
  end as Val2
from @TestTable
```

Result:

```
Val1        Val2
----------- -----------
30          40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM TestTable WHERE [value] <= @number ORDER BY [value] DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM TestTable WHERE [value] >= @number ORDER BY [value]
```

Alternatively

```
SELECT
  (SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM TestTable WHERE [value] <= @number ORDER BY [value] DESC) AS [min],
  (SELECT TOP 1 [value] FROM TestTable WHERE [value] >= @number ORDER BY [value]) AS [max]
```

Have an index on the `[value]` field and check if you want `>= / <=` or `>= / <` ranges.g

Comment: @Will Thanks! :) *Looking at the question again, I think this is not the answer. To the problem maybe, but not to the question as it's been asked.*

Comment: no problem, I had to check and double-check I was 'doing the right thing' with that edit - that sort of query always trips me up!

Comment: rereading the question I see what you mean - a bit of an odd requirement, hence the couple of answers answering the 'more obvious' variant of the question!

Answer (score 0):

You'd replace the 34 with a variable containing the value you want to find, but I think this should get you what you want.

```
select
(select top 1 * from TestTable
where value > 34
order by value),

(select top 1 * from TestTable
where value < 34
order by value desc)
```

Comment: Subqueries with `TOP` also need `ORDER BY`

Comment: You're missing an ORDER BY on your first query.